# Biosketch for New Researchers

Tags: funding, nih

How do you describe your Research Support (part D of NIH's biosketch) if you've never been a named member of a grant?  For junior researchers, NIH provides [helpful guidance here](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/forms/biosketch.htm) on parts A (personal statement) and C (contribution to science).  Certain applicants can skip the Research Support section (high school students, applicants for predoctoral or postdoctoral fellowships, applicants for dissertation grants), but what if you're none of those?  I don't want to leave it entirely blank, but I don't want to mislead reviewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with @Formite's answer. My perspective is mostly related to NSF grants and faculty applications, not NIH proposals, but it's *very* common and not at all bad for new faculty to have nothing to list for external support. Many people list their university start-up funds -- this is a good thing to do, since it shows university commitment. I think it *would* be seen as misleading to write down grants for which you weren't a PI, for example things that funded you as a graduate student or postdoc.

Comment: I asked various PIs who funded me throughout grad school, and they agreed with @Raghu that it was more accurate to leave the section blank.

Comment: Note that NIH-style sketches have a space for "Role" where you can specify non-PI roles, and that these grants show up eRA Commons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this by looking at my early biosketches and seeing what I did.

Basically, I very much doubt your research support section is *blank*. Research support is *not* necessarily just the grants you were the PI on, but any grant you have ever been funded on - so for example I listed the training grant I was on as a graduate student.

If you've never genuinely been funded in *any way*, then I would say leave it blank.